# file .exe generated by pysinstaller doesn't work with cantera python library

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cantera

I'm trying to make an .exe file of a python script using the cantera library with help of PyInstaller module.

I'm working with python 3.9 and Pyinstaller 5.13.1.

My Script is very simple :

```
import numpy as np
import cantera as ct
print(np.zeros(2))
S = ct.Solution('gri30.cti')
```

I'm working in virtual environnement with all packages necessary installed.
When I execute my script with python in venv everything is ok, the script work well.

I can generate the .exe file with this command line : pyinstaller script.py --collect-all cantera

The .exe is correctly created is dist folder.

When I execute the .exe in the virtual env everything is ok, but when I try to run it in arbitrary folder I have this log :

```
[0. 0.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\t-vgate-3\\dev1\tst.py", line 7, in <module>
    S=ct.Solution("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\gri30.cti")
  File "build\python\cantera\base.pyx", line 71, in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase.__cinit__
  File "build\python\cantera\base.pyx", line 137, in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase._cinit
  File "build\python\cantera\base.pyx", line 256, in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase._init_cti_xml
cantera._cantera.CanteraError:
*******************************************************************************
CanteraError thrown by call_ctml_writer:
Error converting input file "C:\Users\Downloads\gri30.cti" to CTML.
Python command was: 'python'
The exit code was: 1
-------------- start of converter log --------------
sys.path: ['', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "cantera\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._cantera import *
ImportError: No module named _cantera
--------------- end of converter log ---------------
*******************************************************************************

[14960] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

In this case, numpy seems to work well but not cantera.

I think that Cantera doesn't use the python interpreter of the .exe file.

Somebody have an idea to solve this issue ? Or maybe some test to do ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Cantera is working, but it cannot read such file. It is possible that it needs some external library (DLL). Find out which library it requires (there should be in the documents), and then you should add it as required file in pyinstaller. It is a bit messy using pyinstaller on libraries which requires extra files (and without receipts in pycharm). It is a lot of test and error (and reading documentation and sources)

Comment: I think I have found the problem source.

Cantera library try to use C program that convert cti file to ctml file. 

This C program call a python script with executable wich is give by "PYTHON_CMD" environment variable. 

The problem is that the python executable is wrapped in the executable when running this program in c.

I tried to pass venv python executable path in PYTHON_CMD before execute pyinstaller but it doesn't work. 

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to make sure that pyinstaller is also packaging the `_cantera.dll` file. In addition, the CTI format is deprecated and removed in the most recent version. If you use a YAML input file, you will not require Python to load the file.

Comment: Your tags include `python-3.x` but the path in the error is for Python 2.7. Which is it? What versions of Cantera and Python are you trying to use?